# Resolve error not working

Tags: routes, angular-ui-router, restangular

I'm using ui.router and Restangular.
In `$stateProvider` I have state with

```
resolve: {
    dane: function (daneTematy) {
        var promise = daneTematy.getItem(-1);
        return promise;
    }
}
```

For tests it always gest error and execute `$stateChangeError`

Here is func from service:

```
function getItem(id, params) {
    return Restangular.one(zrodlo, id).get()
        .then(getItemSuccess)
        .catch(restangularError);

    function getItemSuccess(response) {
        $log.info('Mam dane elementu - Źródło: ' + zrodlo);
        response.doHistorii();
        return response;
    }
}

function restangularError(response) {
    $log.error("Error with status code", response.status);
    return response;
}
```

It's not working - it gets to `restangularError` but not to `$stateChangeError`. When I delete `catch` it works well:

```
function getItem(id, params) {
    return Restangular.one(zrodlo, id).get()
        .then(getItemSuccess);

    function getItemSuccess(response) {
        $log.info('Mam dane elementu - Źródło: ' + zrodlo);
        response.doHistorii();
        return response;
    }
}
```

What is a problem with `restangularError`? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your error handler, you mark the error as being resolved. So `ui-router` gets a resolved promise and therefore does not cause a `$stateChangeError`.
To solve this, you have to reject a promise within an error handler if you couldn't fix it. See this excerpt from the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> When comparing deferreds/promises to the familiar behavior of
>   try/catch/throw, think of reject as the throw keyword in JavaScript.
>   This also means that if you "catch" an error via a promise error
>   callback and you want to forward the error to the promise derived from
>   the current promise, you have to "rethrow" the error by returning a
>   rejection constructed via reject.

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
  // success: do something and resolve promiseB
  //          with the old or a new result
  return result;
}, function(reason) {
  // error: handle the error if possible and
  //        resolve promiseB with newPromiseOrValue,
  //        otherwise forward the rejection to promiseB
  if (canHandle(reason)) {
   // handle the error and recover
   return newPromiseOrValue;
  }
  return $q.reject(reason);
});
```

For your case this just means you have to modify your error handler as follows (make sure `$q` is available):

```
function restangularError(response) {
    $log.error("Error with status code", response.status);
    return $q.reject(response);
}
```